# How to cache mp4 files in iOS Safari

Tags: caching, mobile-safari, mp4, progressive-web-apps

I'm having the same issue as:
[Why isn't Safari caching mp4 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687499/why-isnt-safari-caching-mp4-files)

But that question is 3 years old with no recent activity and only MY +1 so I wanted to repost the question as this is still an issue.

I have a PWA that plays media offline, but mp4s won't cached in iOS Safari.  My setup works "everywhere" else (Desktop Chrome, Safari, IE as well as Android).

Comment: Maybe size? Hard to tell without your service worker code. Can you upload the code with your question?

Comment: Is there a file size limit on mp4 files?  I didn't post my code, originally, because it works fine, except for Safari mobile.  But I'll redact any private code and post that if it will help.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. I've set `Cache-Control: max-age=86400`, and can see it in the response headers for the .mp4. Caching works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work at all in Safari, even though it does cache other types of responses. My videos are very small (1-2MB), so I doubt size is an issue. @WayneF.Kaskie, have you figured anything out?

Comment: Same issue to me. Works also fine at Safari Desktop. But not on iOS